# Using client script code in emptydata template gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, gridview

i use this code in order to create pop-up messages to the users if there is something needed to be prompt

**Note: this is a code in C#**

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "messagebox", "<script>$(document).ready( function() { csscody.error('<br/><h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Error</h1><br/><left> 'Hello!' </left>');});</script>", false);
```

is it possible to use it inside the empty data template of a gridview?

**NOTE: this is a code inside the gridview in ASPX file**

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <center>
        No Record Found
    </center>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

so that instead of outputting a Text it will show a pop-up of no record.

any guide? thank you..

Sorry im new to This.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you bind gridview you can check for the records. show the alert if no records found.

otherwise continue the binding.

```
if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count <1)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "messagebox", "<script>$(document).ready( function() { csscody.error('<br/><h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Error</h1><br/><left> 'Hello!' </left>');});</script>", false);
}
else
{
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: so i should not use the empty data template?? thanks! :)